# At most one query SQL

Tags: sql

I'm doing some exercises in a basic SQL and I have the following problem:

Let us consider the following relational schema about actors and films:

- **Film:** FilmCode , Title, Filmmaker, Year
- **Actor:** ActorCode , Surname, Name, Sex, BirthDate, Nationality
- **Interpretation:** Film, Actor, Role

Let us assume that more than one actor may act in a film and that the same actor may act in more than one film and in a given film, each involved actor plays only one role.
Filmmaker to be univocally identified by his/her surname and each film to be directed by a single filmmaker.

The query I have to write is:

> the actors that acted together in at most one film directed by the filmmaker Quentin Tarantino.

How can I translate the "at most one film" into SQL language?

What I have wrote so far is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A1.ActorCode, A2.ActorCode
FROM Actor A1 A2, Interpretation I1 I2
WHERE I1.Film=I2.Film and I1.Actor <> I2.Actor and A1.ActorCode= I1.Actor and A2.ActorCode=I2.ActorCode and exists unique (
    Select *
    From Film F
    Where I1.Film=F.FilmCode and F.Filmmaker=’Tarantino’
    )
```

But that's not the point

Comment: What have you tried so far? You are supposed to show the effort you made before posting a question.

Comment: A HAVING clause is typically used for that kind of conditions.

Comment: What kind of SQL is this? For example; MySql, SQL Server, sqlite, postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
I.Actor, I2.Actor
FROM  Interpretation I 
INNER JOIN FIlm F
ON F.Filmmaker=’Tarantino’
and F.FilmCode = I.Film
INNER JOIN Interpretation I2
ON I.Film = I2.Film
and I2.Actor <> I.Actor
and I2.Actor not in (SELECT Actor 
                     FROM  Interpretation I3
                     INNER JOIN FIlm F1
                     ON F1.Filmmaker=’Tarantino’
                     and F1.FilmCode = I3.Film
                     and F1.FilmCode <> I.Film      #All other tarantino films
                     WHERE I3.Actor = I.Actor)
```